# String contains() function with Scanner in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, contains

```
System.out.println("Enter a string:");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = sc.nextLine();
if (str.contains("\n")) {
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

to the above piece of code the input string `one\ntwo` does not print "yes"

but the below code prints "yes"

```
String str = "one\ntwo";
if (str.contains("\n")) {
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

Could anyone suggest the reason for such a result?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%9) for `nextLine()`?

Comment: I wonder at the meaning of this magical phrase: "excluding any line separator at the end."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `one\ntwo` in console input `\n` is treated as two characters: `\` and `n`, but when you write `"\n"` in code in String literal, then it represents line separator.

To check if your input contains `\` character followed by `n` use `contains("\\n")` - to create `\` literal we need to escape it by writing it as `"\\"` because it is special character in String (used for instance to create `\n`, `\r` `\t`, or `\"`).

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the `\` is the 'escape' character. If you use `\` in a String declaration, it is never literally put into the String, but used to escape the character right after it. For instance, you can use it to escape the double quote:

```
String str = "A double quote: \""; \\
```

You can also escape the escape character:

```
String str = "A backslash : \\";
```

The escape character is also used in meta-characters like `\n`. If you want to literally use those in a string, you have to escape them as well:

```
String str = "A newline character: \\n";
```

And that last example is exactly what Java does automatically for you if you retrieve the input from the System.in. It gets the literal `\n`, not the meta-character new-line.

So to summarize: inputting `\n` via the System.in is equivalent to directly setting a String to `\\n`.

Comment: @Somdutta nextLine() does what its javadoc says it does. Read the javadoc, and you'll have your answer.